# How to make a query with group_concat in sql server/powerpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, powerpivot

I need help on my query. I am trying to concatenate DonorIntent so that each BudgetNbr has a one to one relationship with the DonorIntnet field. Currently I am exlcuding the BudgetNbrs with multiple DonorIntent (820655 and 820885)

The below hasn't worked for me so any help would be great!

```
SELECT
  vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetNbr
  ,vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetName
  ,ODSBudgetIndexCurrent.OrgCode
  ,ODSBudgetIndexCurrent.BudgetStatus
  ,DonorIntent =  STUFF(( 
SELECT ',' + vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.DonorIntent
      FROM vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary di
      WHERE di.BudgetNbr = vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetNbr 
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM
  vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary
  INNER JOIN SOMOrgDeptGroups
    ON vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.Org_dept = SOMOrgDeptGroups.OrgDeptLevel
  INNER JOIN ODSBudgetIndexCurrent
    ON vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetNbr = ODSBudgetIndexCurrent.BudgetNbr
WHERE
  SOMOrgDeptGroups.ExtFundExpGroup = N'ADMIN'
  AND ODSBudgetIndexCurrent.BudgetType IN (N'06', N'54')
  AND vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetNbr NOT IN (N'820655', N'820885')
GROUP BY
  vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetNbr
  ,vwGEGiftEndowmentSummary.BudgetName
  ,DonorIntent
  ,ODSBudgetIndexCurrent.OrgCode
  ,ODSBudgetIndexCurrent.BudgetStatus
```

Comment: Hasn't worked is quite vague.

Comment: sorry, I get an error message in powerpivot saying that the BudgetNbr is pulling up duplicates when it is the primary key. This would mean the DonorIntent field is not concatenating correctly.

Comment: Try renaming that field with STUFF something other than an existing column.

Comment: Like this (same error message appears)? DonorIntents =  STUFF((

Comment: Error message: Column 'BudgetNbr' in Table 'GE Purpose Intent' contains a duplicate value '820885' and this is not allowed for columns on the one side of a many-to-one relationship or for columns that are used as the primary key of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved. I needed to remove GROUP BY DonorIntent and place into the subquery